# Create XML tree from observable collection

Tags: silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

I have an obeservable collection _kidlist and I want to create an XML doc with 1 parent node Daddy and a child node for each kid.
I'm a complete noob when it comes to LINQ to xml but how would I do this?
When I iterate the collection I get a Parent node Daddy for eacht child but I want one parent node and N kid nodes

```
foreach (kiddo _kid in _kidlist)
        {
             XElement Daddy =          new XElement( "Daddy",              
             new XElement( "Kid"),
                 new XElement( "Name", _kid.Name),                  
                 new XElement( "Age", _kid.Age )));
        }
```

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var document =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement(
            "Daddy",
            from kid in _kidlist
            select new XElement(
                "Kid",
                new XElement("Name", kid.Name),
                new XElement("Age", kid.Age))));
```